# Update price function; woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I am looking to update the price of a product AFTER it has been purchased.

The idea is that when a product has been sold a specific amount of times, the price would be programatically raised to a predetermined amount.

I found the woocommerce_payment_complete hook, which looks like it will get me into the right spot to make the update, but I can't find a function that will update the price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do believe I found it!

```
update_post_meta($post_id, '_regular_price', '10'):
```

Comment: I was going to say that the price is merely post meta, looks like you found it. By the way, try using the code format button in the editor when posting code.

Comment: aahh, right, code format button! thanks helga.  still new to this :D

Comment: No problem. You can still edit the answer to format it. I tried but it wasn't a big enough edit to permit me to do it. Also don't forget to accept the answer as the correct one when you are able.